# Activity is null when using Microsoft Hosting Extensions and net472

Tags: c#, trace, open-telemetry

I am trying to use OpenTelemetry with my net472 app that uses Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.

I create my host like this:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddOpenTelemetry().WithTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
                    {
                        tracerProviderBuilder
                            .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("MySample"))
                            .AddConsoleExporter()
                            .AddSource(serviceName);
                    }).StartWithHost();
                })
                .Build();
```

If I then try to create a new activity like this, it is null:

```
var activitySource = new ActivitySource(serviceName);
using var activity = activitySource.StartActivity("Hello");
```

If instead I register OpenTelemetry like this, it works just fine:

```
using var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
                .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("MySample"))
                .AddSource(serviceName)
                .AddConsoleExporter()
                .Build();
```

How can I get an ActivitySource that has the configured listener using the first approach of creating a Host?

Comment: I have exact the same issue right now. Did you found a solution?

Comment: Not yet, no....

Comment: I've found out that it works only sometimes on my solution. So most of the time the created activity is null but sometimes the listener has subscribed and it works as expected, which is really strange because i did not changed anything related to the telemetry.

Comment: Hm, maybe this behaviour is related to the time all this stuff is registered to the di container.

Comment: I finally found a solution for my specific case. I'll post it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is to resolve the TracerProvider using the ServiceCollection. That way the listener gets subscribed and ActivitySource is able to start activities.

This is how I register the services.

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddSingleton(new ActivitySource(serviceName));
                    services.AddOpenTelemetry().WithTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
                    {
                        tracerProviderBuilder
                            .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("MySample"))
                            .AddConsoleExporter()
                            .AddSource(serviceName);
                    });
                })
                .Build();
```

And then when `TracerProvider` is resolved, it's build using the configured `TracerProvider`:

```cs
using var tracerProvider = ServiceLocator.GetService<TracerProvider>();
var activitySource = ServiceLocator.GetService<ActivitySource>();

// Now this doesn't provide a null object
using var activity = activitySource.StartActivity("Hello");
```

Just for reference, this is ServiceLocator:

```cs
public static class ServiceLocator
    {
        internal static IHost Host { get; set; }

        public static T GetService<T>() where T : class
        {
            return (T)Host.Services.GetService(typeof(T));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

So the `AddOpenTelemetry` extension in the `OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting` package doesn't do much. It does (essentially) this:

```cs
services.TryAddEnumerable(
   ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHostedService, TelemetryHostedService>());

internal sealed class TelemetryHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public TelemetryHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // The sole purpose of this HostedService is to ensure all
        // instrumentations, exporters, etc., are created and started.
        Initialize(this.serviceProvider);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    internal static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Debug.Assert(serviceProvider != null, "serviceProvider was null");

        var meterProvider = serviceProvider!.GetService<MeterProvider>();
        if (meterProvider == null)
        {
            HostingExtensionsEventSource.Log.MeterProviderNotRegistered();
        }

        var tracerProvider = serviceProvider!.GetService<TracerProvider>();
        if (tracerProvider == null)
        {
            HostingExtensionsEventSource.Log.TracerProviderNotRegistered();
        }
    }
}
```

Its sole purpose is to access the `TracerProvider` and/or `MeterProvider` to start the OTel SDK once the `IServiceProvider` is available. It does this by registering an `IHostedService` which is a special service the .NET hosts (generic or web) know to look for and invoke.

I just replied over on https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues/4276. When I use **an actual host** on `net472`, everything works fine.

It is unclear to me why some of the above is not working. A couple examples seem to be calling "Build" without "Run" which won't work. It is during the "Run" phase where `IHostedService`s are started. @endeffects snippet seems like it should work, but it is missing the registration pieces.

My guess as to what is going on is for these .NET Framework applications no host is being used, only `IServiceCollection` \ `IServiceProvider`. In that case, request the providers directly...

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddOpenTelemetr().WithTracing().WithMetrics();

using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

// Start OTel SDK
var tracerProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TracerProvider>();
var meterProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MeterProvider>();
```

Note: In that code you do NOT need to dispose either `TracerProvider` or `MeterProvider` as they are accessed through the `IServiceProvider` and will be disposed when it is disposed.

Worth noting is that there is no requirement to use the `IServiceCollection` \ `IServiceProvider` *at all* on .NET Framework. It is a matter of preference. The OTel .NET SDK ships the `Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder` & `Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder` APIs specifically to support .NET Framework (also people who may want multiple providers).

Further reading: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/990deee419ab4c1449efd628bed3df57a50963a6/docs/trace/customizing-the-sdk#building-a-tracerprovider

Comment: The solution works not just for .NET Framework but for Core as well. I encountered the problem during testing – no activity listeners were being registered because my testing setup didn't require to actually start the host (only to build it), so hosted services weren't being started, which led to no listeners being created. Simply resolving `TraceProvider` and `MeterProvider` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint, i tried to adopt this on my .net core 7 application.
The following code seems to fix the bug for me too.

```
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.UseTelemetry();
...
app.Run();

public static void UseTelemetry(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    _ = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<TracerProvider>();
}
```

Comment: Good. Thanks for sharing. I guess this is just some excerpt from your code, but TracerProvider needs to be disposed, unless it shares the same lifecycle as your app (which I assume it does).